# There is an error when creating a table in the Sequelize migration in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, migration

When I create two tables Products and ProductColor in **mysql**, and add references for ProductColor, I encounter the error:
**ERROR:** Can't create table etradeshop.productcolors (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed
Here is my code:

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
    async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.createTable('Products', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            productName: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            price: {
                type: Sequelize.DOUBLE
            },
            description: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            },
            soldOut: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            stock: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            }
        });
    },
    async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.dropTable('Products');
    }
};
```

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
    async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.createTable('ProductColors', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                autoIncrement: true
            },

            productId: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                references: {
                    model: "Products",
                    key: "id",
                }
            },

            color: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING

            }
        });
    },
    async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.dropTable('ProductColors');
    }
};
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please add DBMS type you use in post's tags. BY the way in PostgreSQL these two migrations works perfectly fine.